# Проблема с @keyup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova

У меня есть компонент - https://pastebin.com/CFDfbfab. когда что то набирается в поле, вызывается событие `searchItems`, которое через `$emit` передается в основной код и там вызывается вот так

```
searchItems: function (event) {
  let self = this
  if (this.timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer._id)
  }
  if ((event.q).indexOf(',') === -1) {
    self.q = event.q
    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
      alert(event.q)
      self.isLoading = true
      axios.post(self.$root.apiLink + 'geo/street', {
        q: event.q,
        lang: self.$ml.current,
        place: self.city
      }, {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.user).auth_key)}
      }).then(function (response) {
        self.isLoading = false
        self.citiesObject = response.data.data
      })
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    self.citiesObject.forEach(function (e) {
      if (e.name.indexOf(event.q) === -1) {
        e.show = false
      } else {
        e.show = true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Сам компонент подключается так

```
<select-address
  v-bind:show-address="select_address"
  v-on:closeAddress="selectLocation"
  v-on:searchItems="searchItems"
  v-bind:items="citiesObject"
  v-bind:showFavorite="showFavorite"
  v-on:saveAddress="saveAddress"
></select-address>
```

Суть проблемы: если поле пустое и что то ввести - то выдает пусто. А если что то уже есть в поле - выводит верно. И из-за этого, когда пользователь вводит что то первый раз - ничего не находит

P.S. Извините, забыл указать важную информацию: проблема на мобилке. То есть, я этот код потом собираю в приложение через cordova. И как раз там проблема

Comment: для начала...в элементе `input` вместо события `keyup`  подписываются на событие `input`

Comment: пробовал, та же ситуация

Comment: по идее, все должно работать. Но я бы еще `searchString` сделал не `null`, а пустой строкой + в качестве теста, можно было бы повесить `watch` на `searchString`

Comment: делал пустой строкой - результат тот же. по поводу `watch` - сейчас поищу как это сделать

Comment: в браузере все работает, проблема на мобилке